# Java Clipboard Paste Checker?

Tags: java, windows, swing, clipboard, paste

I'm using Java with latest JDK 6 up.29 nor JDK 7.
And I'm glad that I could use the Clipboard via Java by using **StringSelection** and **Clipboard** classes. But, I got a new question regarding about this Clipboard.

IF My Operating SYstem Is Windows.
How could I use Java application to Check whether the copied text/object
from the Clipboard is **Only Pasted on specific program** / window, for instances I just allow the object to be pasted in **Notepad**?

**Notepad** here is just example of my purpose for limiting the text/object pasting. 
Could we do it in Java?

I'm still digging about it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

The only way you can possibly restrict it, is by using a MIME-type not understood by any other program.  I do not believe there is one only understood by Notepad.

Comment: i'm wonderng... @Thorbjern Ravn Andersen.
How about to detect what Window is currently in focus by Java app?
I think we should try to do a bit trick when User Pressing CTRL + V,
the Java App start Checking whether the In Focus Window is Notepad instead of others. How about that?

Comment: Are you sure it can't be done? [Transferable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html)'s getter will be called on paste, no? I'm only thinking of this because I *loosely* remember that I had some weird effects when pasting text copied from IntelliJ. I think there was a reaction inside one version of the IDE when I pasted the text somewhere else. *Really* fuzzy memory, but there was something.

Comment: @DreamspacePresident Feel free to investigate further, and make a better answer :)